# How do I reload the child state if there is a change in the parent state controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router with Angular and my idea is that a dropdown in the layout of the UI, which is also the parent state, has a dropdown that will change the data in the child state.

Routing:

```
.state('App', {
            url : '/',
            controller : 'AppController',
            templateUrl : 'views/layout.html',

        })

.state('App.userProfile', {
            parent : 'App',
            url : 'profile',
            templateUrl : 'views/user-profile.html',
            controller : 'UserProfileController'            
        })
```

The HTML dropdown:

```
<div class="top-bar">
<div class="top-bar-logo"></div>
<label>Active team</label>
<select class="clean-custom-select margin-bottom-10"
        ng-options="team._id as team.Name for team in userTeams"
        ng-change="changeActiveTeam(ActiveTeamModel)"
        ng-model="ActiveTeamModel">
<option value="">Choose a team</option>
```

So what I am trying to achieve is when the select dropdown changes the child view will reload with the relevant changes.However, this has to work for all child states. The above code is just an example of one child state, but there are many.

For some more context, the dropdown will have team names. Once the user chooses a team, all the child states should refer to that team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, you can use angular services-  $emit, $broadcast, $on to interchange event and scope change notification on parent child hierarchy .

This will help you to understand this 
[link](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/)

Comment: It seems to have done the trick! I used the $broadcast service to just pass a Boolean value to the other controller. Thank you :)